# Transform a List of IO's into an IO of a List

Tags: scala, io, functional-programming, scala-cats

I want to read a list of files using [cats-effect](https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect)'s IO monad like this:

```scala
def readFile(file: File): IO[Either[CouldNotReadFromFileError, String]] = ???

// lists all the files I want to read
// returns an Either b/c this might encounter i/o problems
def findFiles(): IO[Either[Throwable, Array[File]]] = ???

// reads all files and saves their content in an Array[String]
// ignores files it could not read or find
def readFiles(): IO[Array[String]] = for {
    filesE <- listFiles
    files = filesE match {
      case Left(err) =>
        log.error("An error happened while reading files: " + err.getMessage)
        List[File]()
      case Right(fs) => fs.toList.map(readFile)
    }
    // files has type: List[IO[Either[CouldNotReadFromFileError, String]]]
    // to continue here I'd like to have a: IO[List[Either[CouldNotReadFromFileError, String]]]
    ???
} yield ???
```

Now to continue my computation inside the for-yield-construction I'd like to transform my `List[IO[Either[CouldNotReadFromFileError, String]]]` into a `IO[List[Either[CouldNotReadFromFileError, String]]]`. I know that I can probably do something like this using [cat's traverse](https://www.scala-exercises.org/cats/traverse), but cannot figure out how exactly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This isn't directly related to your question, but is there a reason you're carrying around the `Throwable` in an `Either` instead of failing in `IO`?

Comment: The `findFiles` method is defined in an seperate `io` package, so I thought I'd be a good idea to return information on why it failed to the caller.

Comment: You can still return that information by failing in `IO`, though.

Comment: You mean using sth like `leftMap` to repackage the errors into my own case classes? That is what I am actually planning to do (thanks to a previous answer of yours to another question); Just not really interesting for this question so I left it like that for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sequence` is enough for what you want:

```
import java.io.File
import cats.effect.IO
import cats.implicits._

final class CouldNotReadFromFileError extends RuntimeException("message")

object TestTest {
  def readFile(file: File): IO[Either[CouldNotReadFromFileError, String]] = ???

  def findFiles: IO[Either[Throwable, Array[File]]] =
    ???

  // reads all files and saves their content in an Array[String]
  // ignores files it could not read or find
  def readFiles(): IO[Array[String]] =
    for {
      filesE <- findFiles
      files = filesE match {
        case Left(err) =>
          List.empty
        case Right(fs) =>
          fs.toList.map(readFile)
      }
      // The type ascription below is just for demonstration purposes.
      // You don't need to keep it there.
      a <- files.sequence: IO[List[Either[CouldNotReadFromFileError, String]]]
    } yield {
      ???
    }
}
```

Comment: Strange I am getting: `value sequence is not a member of List[cats.effect.IO[Either[io.CouldNotReadFromFileError,String]]]
[error]     a <- files.sequence: IO[List[Either[CouldNotReadFromFileError, String]]]`. I did `import cats.syntax.all` and `import cats.implicits`

Comment: Intellij can find it though. Just compilation fails.

Comment: No idea why, but it worked when I moved the `import cats.implicits` directly over the method. :)

Comment: @FlorianBaierl `import cats._`, `import cats.data._`, `import cats.implicits._`. See [here](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/imports.html)

Comment: @Lasf Right, I've already gotten used to only writing `import cats.implicits._` so I totally forgot about that. Thanks for reminding me. :)

Comment: @FlorianBaierl If you imported **both** `cats.syntax.all._` and `cats.implicits._` you probably had an ambiguous implicits error. You import *either* (`cats.syntax.all._` and `cats.instances.all._`) *or* `cats.implicits._`.